# Finding initial conditions from the temperature autocorrelation function

Tags: cosmology, temperature, perturbation-theory, correlation-functions, cosmic-microwave-background

So I was reading Mukhanov and in section 9.4 titled Correlation functions and multipoles, he talks about obtaining the auto-correlation function

\begin{equation}
C(\theta) = \bigg\langle \frac{\delta T}{T_0}(\mathbf{l}_1)\frac{\delta T}{T_0}(\mathbf{l}_2)\bigg\rangle
\end{equation}

where $\mathbf{l}_i$ are the incoming photon directions and $\langle \rangle$ denotes averaging over all these directions. Note that we are in the Newtonian gauge where the metric is
\begin{equation}
ds^2 = a(\eta)^2((1+2 \phi)d\eta^2 - (1-2\phi)dx^idx^i)
\end{equation}
So the entire point is that given the correlator $\langle \phi_\mathbf{k}\phi_\mathbf{k'}\rangle$ (these are the Fourier modes of the scalar field $\phi$) we can find the temperature autorcorrelation function. But my question is can we go the other way around? Given the temperature fluctuation correlators, is it possible to find the metric perturbation correlators? Any literature on this would help greatly thanks.